# Div next to an image

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>TheGelu - Coming Soon</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background: #474747 url(http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/letterpress/demo/bg.png);
}
p.margin {  
  margin-left:300px;
}
p.box { 
  margin-left:300px;
}
h1 {
  font: 60px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; letter-spacing: -5px;  
  color: #999; text-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #2a2a2a;
}
boxy {
  border: 0px solid #db9b20;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
  moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
  -moz-border-shadow: 0pc;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(240, 240, 240, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(240, 240, 240, 1);
  box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(240, 240, 240, 1);
}
</style>
</head>
<body><h1><center>TheGelu *-*</center></h1>
<p class="margin"><img src="RoundRound.png" alt="" width="136" height="137" /><img src="arrowSignal.png" alt="" width="318" height="126" /></p><div style="width:400px;height:300px;float:right;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;background-color:#FFFFFF;-webkit-box-shadow: #000000 2px 2px 2px;-moz-box-shadow: #000000 2px 2px 2px; box-shadow: #000000 2px 2px 2px;">Pretty Text Here!</div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want the box to be exactly next to the arrow (on the right). How can I do that? I've tried float but I don't know how to put it up.

Live version at http://thegelu.bl.ee/test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?[image]
1. p.margin, add float:left;
2. text box div, also add float:left;
Done.

Edit:you mean like this?[image]
Because your arrow uses an image and that image has a transparent background that is wider than the image itself. 
Solutions:
1. modify your image and remove the blank space
2. no need to modify image, just add margin-left:-90px; to your text box div

Comment: I need it exactly next to the arrow.

Comment: Thank you!! I forgot that the image had that blank space!!

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `div` in your `p.margin` and specify on it `style="display: inline-block"`.

Comment: I moved it. Now what could I do to get it exactly next to the arrow?

Comment: @user3142039 did you remove the float and set `display` as I suggested?

Comment: Yep. Haha I just noticed the picture is the problem. Thanks!